# What is the correct way to tune (and scan for) an ATSC Channel?

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

I'm trying to understand how most applications perform ATSC tuning. Assume that I already have an ATSC tune request that I've acquired via

```
ITuneRequest *pITuneRequest = NULL;
pATSCTuningSpace->CreateTuneRequest(&pTuneRequest)`
```

It seems that there are three prevalent methods:

1) **Build a list of all major.minor channels and map them to a physical channel**, then tune to that physical channel whenever a major.minor is requested. This map is built via code like this:

```
for i = 2 to 69
    tune_to_physical_channel(i)
    if (tuner_has_lock())
         add_to_known_list(i, major_of(i), minor_of(i));
next
```

The UI only presents list of major.minor channels to the user.

The problem that I'm seeing here is that I seem to get duplicate mappings; there are times when I tune physical channel 30 and see 43.1, and other times when I tune it, but instead see 43.2! Why would this be happening?

2) **Tune to major.minor directly.** Allow direct input of both the major and minor channels, and do not use physical channels at all. I've tried this using several local channels: 8.1, 8.2, 43.1, 43.2, 43.3, 49.1, 49.2.

8.1 and 8.2 tune perfectly if a build a tune request and set parameters like this:

```
IATSCChannelTuneRequest* pIATSCChannelTuneRequest = NULL;
IATSCLocator *pIATSCLocator = NULL;
hr = pITuneRequest->QueryInterface( IID_IATSCChannelTuneRequest, 
            (void**)&pIATSCChannelTuneRequest); 
pIATSCChannelTuneRequest->put_Channel(lMajorChannel);
pIATSCChannelTuneRequest->put_MinorChannel(lMinorChannel);
::CoCreateInstance( CLSID_ATSCLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IATSCLocator,       
            (void**)&pIATSCLocator);
pIATSCLocator->put_CarrierFrequency(-1);
pIATSCLocator->put_SymbolRate(-1);
pIATSCLocator->put_PhysicalChannel(-1);
pIATSCChannelTuneRequest->put_Locator(pIATSCLocator);
```

The other channels never tune. Why? Other applications (such as WinTV) tune everything correctly.

3) **Build a list of major.minor channels by scanning a list of known frequencies for a given geographic area**. Some applications seed themselves with location-based known frequencies, [such as this one](https://github.com/openpli-arm/dvb-apps/blob/master/util/scan/atsc/us-ATSC-center-frequencies-8VSB), [this one](https://github.com/gfto/dvblast/blob/master/extra/dvbiscovery/dvbiscovery_atsc.conf), and [this one](http://www.filewatcher.com/p/vdr-atscepg-0.3.0.tgz.42456/atscepg-0.3.0/scanner.h.html). Note that all of those are US Specific.

I haven't actually tried it yet, but my plan would be to supply a list, and build a mapping of major.minor -> frequency, similar to #1:

```
foreach (frequency f in frequency_array)
    tune_to_frequency (f)
    if (tuner_has_lock())
         add_to_known_list(f, major_of(f), minor_of(f));
next
```

So again the question is: **How do applications implement scanning/tuning for ATSC channels?**

Comment: How is your known list built? If the physical channel is the index of an array, double mappings are impossible and a duplicate would simply replace the first mapping. That would at least help with 1). I assume the mapping is done only once? Or do you map repeatedly? The latter would also explain why the mapping yields inconsistent results.

Comment: >double mappings are impossible  -- that's kind of the point of my question. In method 1, I sometimes see a tune request to physical channel 30 result in tuning to 43.1, and sometimes see the tune request tune me to 43.2. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to this behavior and I would have expected a 1:1 relationship for physical -> major.minor mappings. The last thing I ask of method 1's behavior is... why is this happening? I don't want to replace the first mapping, because you never know which of the two minor channels will actually be tuned.

Comment: The relationship is not necessarily 1:1. Actually unless I understand the system wrong, the mapping is simply majors to physical, while the minors are merely several data streams provided on the same channel. This means there are a lot more programs (major.minor) than channels (physical).

Comment: That was one scenario that had occurred to me. I thought about writing it up, but this question had already almost become a TL;DR. Is it possible that the correct way to scan for channels is: `for (i=2 to 69) { tune_physical(i); currentmajor = get_major_of(i); for (j = 1 to max_minor) { tune_major_minor(currentmajor, j); } }`?

Comment: It should work without the call to `tune_physical(i)`, as physical maps 1:1 to major (your `get_major_of(i)` is this mapping by the way). So unless you want to catch strange exceptions I'm unaware of, `tune_major_minor(currentmajor, j)` should be enough.

Comment: This sounds like my case #2: tune to major.minor directly. This works on 3rd party apps, but only works for certain channels. It doesn't make sense why some channels work, while ALL work under apps like Media Center or WinTV.

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with the parameters, have you tried playing around with them a little?

Comment: @scenia I finally got around to posting an answer to this, if you're curious. The solution that I arrived at doesn't take scanning into account, but I was able to finally successfully tune channels other than 8.1 and 8.2. Thanks for your time and comments back in Feb.

Comment: Wow, that did take a while! Glad to hear you managed to work it out, sorry i couldn't be of more help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, our solution was to not support scanning, and go with method number two: Tune to Major.Minor directly. In my original post, I noted that this was only working for 8.1 and 8.2 in my area.

It turns out, setting `Channel` and `MinorChannel` is not enough. I needed to [cross-reference each major channel](http://www.antennaweb.org) and also set the `PhysicalChannel` (RFChannel) when tuning. So, to tune, we set `Channel`, `MinorChannel`, and `PhysicalChannel` for all requests.

I set all other properties (including `CarrierFrequency`) to -1 in the `TuneRequest`.

Additionally, I found two other resources for doing lookups:

http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/engineering/dtvmaps/
http://www.tvfool.com

As a side note, for our application purposes, it's reasonable to ask users to go look up the physical (RF) channel using antennaweb.org. I'm not sure how you'd still use our approach if the user didn't have this information on-hand.